# Android Emulator Not working Android Studio version 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 Window 7,today my emulator stop working.I have installed all necessary packages and restarted twice thrice times.Even created another AVD device with ram size 726 MB still its not working.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4wKg.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IIrK.png)

Comment: Have you installed `Intel® HAXM` before?

Comment: have you installed HAXM correctly??

Comment: I have installed it,but sdk doesn't show option to uninstall or reinstall it

Comment: Recently updated SDK solved my problem